# Is comparing a variable to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] safe usage?

Tags: php

I am a newbie to PHP still, so excuse this question if it seems silly, but I was wondering if this is safe usage of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

From my reading about what's wrong with it (prone to injection), I was wondering if it safe to compare it.

For example, I want the PHP/CSS stylesheet to change depending on the page the person is on, so in the PHP/CSS, it would have an `if` statement checking `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to see if the page their visiting requires a different stylesheet.

Example:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] === $thisPage) { }
```

Could malicious code affect me this way? Could I simply validate/cleanse it, then use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better code example would be:

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] === $thisPage) { }
```

Still, it depends on the contents of $thisPage. If $thisPage contains `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` too, you should change that to `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

---

If you really can't use alternatives like `__FILE__` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, and make sure you understand the checks involved, yes.

For example, this URL: `http://example.com/sick.php/mwuahahahaha` gives:

```
/sick.php/mwuahahahaha
```

Comparing is allowed, for non-critical things like CSS.

If there's no need to get the requested path (no URL rewrites), use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`.
If you really need `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` (rewrited URL), escape them when outputting (using [`htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`](http://php.net/htmlentities).

Overview of variables:

- `__FILE__`: contains the full filesystem path from the active script. E.g.:
  `<?php /*test.php*/ include 'file.php';?>`
  `<?php /*file.php*/ echo __FILE__;?>`
  Requesting test.php gives something like: `/var/www/file.php` (and not `/var/www/test.php`)
- `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`: contains the filesystem path of the requested script, e.g. `/var/www/test.php`
- `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`: contains the path of the requested script (like a filesystem one, but with the document root stripped), e.g. `/test.php` (even when using rewrited URL's)
- `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`: contains a translated path (`//` -> `/`, `.` and `..` resolved), but with additional path info.
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`: the worst of these, it contains the raw string in the request as in. `GET [REQUEST_URI] HTTP/1.0`. (escaped) nullbytes are still visible in here. This is just the raw data between `GET` (or whatever methode you use) and `HTTP/1.0` (or whatever HTTP version you use)

A comparison of these variables:

I performed this test with `nc`, but `telnet` should suffice too. Server was from http://xampp.org/. The requested file is `test.php`, which contains:

```
<?php
$properties = array('SCRIPT_FILENAME', 'SCRIPT_NAME', 'PHP_SELF', 'REQUEST_URI');
printf("% 15s: %s\n", '__FILE__', __FILE__);
foreach($properties as $property){
     printf('% 15s: %s', $property, $_SERVER[$property]."\n");
}
?>
```

Test:

```
$ nc localhost 80
GET ///somedir/./../////test.php/somedata%20here?q%00=%25 HTTP/1.0


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix)
[stripped]

       __FILE__: /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME: /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php
    SCRIPT_NAME: /////test.php
       PHP_SELF: /////test.php/somedata here
    REQUEST_URI: ///somedir/./../////test.php/somedata%20here?q%00=%25
```

Using `RewriteRule ^page/test test.php`:

```
$ nc localhost 80
GET ///somedir/./../page//.////test/somedata%20here?q%00=%25 HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix)
[stripped]

       __FILE__: /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME: /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php
    SCRIPT_NAME: /test.php
       PHP_SELF: /test.php
    REQUEST_URI: ///somedir/./../page//.////test/somedata%20here?q%00=%25
```

Conclusion: the safest variable to use in most cases is `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`.

Comment: +1 this is the only possible way of misusing PHP_SELF I know of. It  could create problems under some circumstances if used as the base URL for a form or something, but will be safe to use in a comparison like shown by the OP.

Comment: I believe you have it wrong. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] always contains the path of the running script. You're thinking of REQUEST_URI.

Comment: I just tested it again: `http://localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php/whatDidYouSay?%25` gives: `_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /xampp/phpinfo.php/whatDidYouSay`. REQUEST_URI is even worse: `/xampp/phpinfo.php/whatDidYouSay?%25`. This 'feature' is called [`Pathinfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)

Comment: That might be an XAMPP thing, then. You can see a live example here: http://codeacula.com/pages/asdfasdfasdf.php

Comment: http://codeacula.com/pages/asdfasdfasdf.php/WhatDidITellYou?%25: `[PHP_SELF] => /app/webroot/index.php`. You're cheating with rewrited URLs.

Comment: Hah. I am. I think it's a both-right case, unless I'm wrong on that. Modify your answer to contain the variation?

Comment: I just tested on a live server, Apache2 from sources: http://lekensteyn.nl/dump1x.php/WhatDidITellYou%25 still gives:
`[PHP_SELF] => /dump1x.php/WhatDidITellYou%`

Comment: I actually did not know about `__FILE__`. And just to verify, what constitutes at "checks" involved? I figured there would be none in the case that I am using it in. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I updated my post with even more alternatives, and a comparison of those.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is simple and short:
if your files being called directly, like `http://www.example.com/news.php`, your code is all right.
No malicious code can affect your site this way.